# Understanding violin interpretation - guides

Tags: violin, interpretation

Along the lines of "Keyboard Interpretation From the 14th to the 19th Century: An Introduction" by Howard Ferguson, is there a similar work or works catering to the needs of violinists?

Edit: I am editing this after noticing downvotes, maybe from "purists"? I understand book recommendations are off topic on this SE, however, I think this question is broader than just a recommendation.

I understand that interpretation is not something that can be learned from a book alone, and needs thorough study - I am still looking for written/visual material that can aid me in this.

Answer (score 3):

There’s some compendiums, like the Cambridge Companion to Violin or String Quartet. But you’ll find more material (books, multimedia and scientific papers) focusing your search in narrower periods, like Early music, French baroque, Romantic period et cetera, or even search by composers. For example, there’s a great book by Robin Stowell, “The Early Violin and Viola”. He also has good material in Beethoven’s aesthetics. Check it out and good studies! :-)

Comment: Thank you - this is very helpful. In fact, focusing on specific periods is what I started doing recently after I attended a Baroque violin workshop - it was an eye opener.